# ScrollView sliding from bottom to top, programmatically

Tags: android, scrollview

I'd like to have an effect like "end titles" in movies, where participants names to the projects smoothly slide from the bottom to the top.
I was thinking about ScrollView and this is my idea (clearly it doesn't work):
In the onCreate:

```
sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_text);
```

in the onStart:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();
   sv.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });

}
```

In the onWindowsFocusChanged:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    if (hasFocus)
    {   

        int display_h = display.getHeight();
        pos_y = display_h; 
        mScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateScroll);
        mScrollHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateScroll, 0);       

    }
    else
    {   

        mScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateScroll);

    }
}
```

And this is for the Handler:

```
private Runnable mUpdateScroll = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        pos_y = pos_y - 1; 
        sv.scrollTo(0, pos_y);
        mScrollHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateScroll, 100);
    }
};
```

Here, a Log on the pos_y variable correctly shows the changes, from 480 to 0, smoothly.
My idea were that the views scrolls from bottom to top at 10pixels/second.

Unfortunately, the layout inside the scrollview is fully shown at the activity start. In the scrollview I used a classical vertical linearLayout with all the strings inside it, loading in the onCreate.

Someone would help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the moment I've decided to use this other approach, but if anyone have a better suggestion, come on. I've deleted the ScrollView layout and I've only used a classical RelativeLayout with all the text I need to cycle.

In the OnCreate:

```
display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int display_h = display.getHeight();
    pos_y = display_h;
```

In the onWindowsFocusChanged:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    if (hasFocus)
    {   

    RelativeLayout r_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeTables);          
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)r_main.getLayoutParams();          
      params.leftMargin = 0;
      params.topMargin = pos_y;
      r_main.setLayoutParams(params);
mScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateScroll);
            mScrollHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateScroll, 0);       

}
else
{   

    mScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateScroll);

}
```

}

And finally in the runnable:

```
private Runnable mUpdateScroll = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    pos_y = pos_y - 1; 
    RelativeLayout r_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeTables);          
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)r_main.getLayoutParams();          
          params.leftMargin = 0;
          params.topMargin = pos_y;
          r_main.setLayoutParams(params);
    mScrollHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateScroll, 100);

// the running cycle:
if (pos_y<-display.getHeight()) {
                    pos_y = display.getHeight();
                }

    }
};
```

It works.